# make error compiling aircrack

Tags: aircrack-ng

I have tried to install aircrack on my Ubuntu terminal step by step from [their website instructions](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#installing_aircrack-ng_from_source)

Everything went fine until the step `make`,
when I type it and press enter I get this error message:

```
$ make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/anan/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3  -mavx2 -DJOHN_AVX2 -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude -DSIMD_CORE  wpaclean.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o -o wpaclean -Losdep -losdep -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:247: recipe for target 'wpaclean' failed
make[1]: * * * [wpaclean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anan/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4/src'
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: * * * [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libssl-dev
```

You are specifically missing `libnl-genl-3-dev` which needs to be installed along with the other 2 packages listed.